# Author: = <=> Even though user.name is set in git config

Tags: git

My git log is always showing "`Author: = <=>`":

```
commit 75740449b54264a3f8aa44659dc253d4dbabff00

Author: = <=>

Date:   Mon Nov 14 15:44:04 2016 +1100
```

However my .gitconfig correctly contains:

```
[user]

      name = my.name

      email = my.name@myemail.com
```

I have the following in my environment:

```
$ echo $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME

my.name

$ echo $GIT_COMMITTER_NAME

my.name
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: is there a .git/config in your project directory? what are its contents?

Comment: What does `git config user.name` and/or `git config user.email` output?

Comment: Setting the `user.name` and `user.email` configs wont affect old commits, only new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have in your path a `git-commit` script which might override the git command commit. Or a git wrapper (like the one proposed [in `git-override`](https://github.com/skuroda/git-override))

Check that a new commit still display the issue.
If it does, make one with:

```
git commit --author="Name <email>" -m "whatever"
```

And see if the issue persists.